# how I can delete row in gridview without queries in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

There is my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
    ForeColor="#333333" Width="600px" OnRowEditing="Grid_RowEditing" OnRowDeleting="Grid_RowDeleting"
    OnRowUpdating="Grid_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleted="Grid_RowDeleted" OnRowCancelingEdit="Grid_RowCancelingEdit"
    ShowFooter="True" DataKeyNames="id">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="true" ShowHeader="true" />
        <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" NullDisplayText="sad" />
        <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="TotalPrice" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to delete row this method

```
protected void Grid_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
    Grid.DeleteRow(index);
}
```

but after several seconds I get

> This webpage is not available

What should a I do?

there is my datasource. I want to delete row without deleting records in db

```
var query = 
    from order in mydb.Order_Details
    join orderdetail in mydb.Order_Details on order.OrderID equals orderdetail.OrderID
    join product in mydb.Products on order.ProductID equals product.ProductID
    where order.OrderID==editOrderID
    select new
    {
        ProductID = order.Product.ProductID,
        ProductName = order.Product.ProductName,
        Quantity = order.Quantity,
        UnitPrice = order.UnitPrice
    }
    into f
    group f by f.ProductID;

var outputData = query.Select(g => new
    {
        id= g.Key,
        ProductID = g.FirstOrDefault().ProductID,
        ProductName = g.FirstOrDefault().ProductName,
        Quantity = g.FirstOrDefault().Quantity,
        UnitPrice = g.FirstOrDefault().UnitPrice
    });

Grid.DataSource = outputData;
Grid.DataBind();
```

Comment: I would imagine you get a stackoverflow, because your `Grid_RowDeleting` gets recalled each time over the `Grid.DeleteRow(index)` command. You should delete the data from your DataSource/DataTable. So in this case, this part of your code is missing to give a meaningfull answer

Comment: after Grid.DeleteRow(index); bind your GridView again...check it........e.g  Grid.DataBind();

Comment: @Pranav-BitWiser the same result

Comment: @Icepickle. I add code. I know how delete rows when I delete records in DB, but I want to delete only row in grid. As I know I need connect gridview with datable, but I don't know how I can do it, when grid is filled from queries linqsql

Comment: You can get the keys from the DataGrid (i think it's called `Grid.Keys[rowIndex]`) and then get your dataSource, and remove the element from there. You might have to cast outputData first with the ToList(), cause now it's filled with anonymous classes, And then rebind the datasource. I don't really have time to go in detail now, but i might answer tonight if nobody did so far :)

Comment: And as an extra suggestion, turn on remote debugging in your web.config and turn of any friendly error messages in internet explorer, so you could actually see the error report from the website, instead of the not available message ;)

Comment: Ok. I will wait your full answer.
And I will try to do it myself. Thanks

Comment: Instead of deleting from UI you can make that row "invisible" in RowDeleting event -GridView1.rows[i].visible=false;

Comment: Shall i post it as answer? so that you can check/mark it as your desired answer...:)

Comment: @Pranav-BitWiser. yes, u can

Comment: @user4523894 -posted it as an answer..Done..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of deleting from UI you can make that row `invisible` in RowDeleting event -

```
GridView1.rows[i].visible=false;
```